# Adding Users to an array in existing Mongodb collection - Mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a **collection named "tasks"**.

```
var newTask = {
            name: req.body.newTask,
            room: req.body.newRoom,
            users: [req.body.newUser]
        };
```

I want to insert users in tasks. 
**For example** task named "Session" can have multiple users.

```
{
name: Session,
room: ElementRoom
users: [steve, john]
}
```

**What I'm doing is something like this:-**

```
app.post('/room/task/user', function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.update(
    { name: req.body.taskName },
    { $push: { users: req.body.username } }
    )
});
```

But I'm getting this error:-
TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

what am i doing wrong?

**Thanks a lot in advance**

Comment: Are you sure you have a collection `tasks` on the db you have connected !!

Comment: Yes I have a collection named tasks.

Comment: Please post the full code here. What that `db` variable assigned with ?

Comment: `code`
var db = null;
//var messages;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/hermius", function(err, dbconn){
 if (!err) {
  console.log("We are connected");
        db = dbconn;   
 }
 else
 {
  console.log("NOT CONNECTED");
 }
});
`/code`

Comment: db is database connection variable

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution:-**

```
app.post('/room/task/user', function(req, res, next){
db.collection('tasks', function(err, tasksCollection){
    tasksCollection.update(
    { name: req.body.taskName },
    { $push: { users: req.body.username } }
    )
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

});